# Keyboard shortcut for Line Number not working in Visual studio 2017

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017

What is the shortcut key to jump to a line in visual studio 2017. I have installed visual studio 2010 and i used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to jump to a specific line. After i installed visual studio 2017, when i use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, it opens Immediate Window.

List of [shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/) in Visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has some problem with `additional Keyboard Mapping scheme` where `Visual Basic 6` was selected. I clicked the `Reset` button and then changed my mapping scheme option to `Default` and it's working fine now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have VS 2017 aswel, and left <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> works for me.

[image: picture of result from left CTRL + G]

Otherwise take a look below 'tools' -> 'options' and then under 'environment' choose 'keyboard'. There you can change them to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Svenmarim, I changed the option in ' Mapping scheme' and it works now.